# Animation From top to Button

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-animation

I'm trying to make a animation from the top to the button.

If I click on a button, he should show a View from top. And if I'm clicking again, he should animate it back to the top. This is, what i have:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btFilterDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btFilterDown);
    Button btFilterUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btFilterUp);
    final View layout = findViewById(R.id.slide);
    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btFilterUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        hideView(layout);
        }
    });

    btFilterDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        showView(layout);
        }
    });
}

private void hideView(final View view){
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.slide_out_up);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(animation);
}

private void showView(final View view){
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.slide_in_down);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Slide_in_down.xml:

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:fromYDelta="-1000"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Slide_out_up.xml:

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="-1000"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

And my main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btFilterDown"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="FILTER!!!"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#99009900" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btFilterUp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=" NO FILTER!!!"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So now I have 2 problems:

First:
The button of my first layout is not visible anymore, if the second layout is over it. I want to make the view, which animated in, transparency. But it looks very bad, if the objects from the first view away.
How can I lay the animated layout over the first, so that all objects on the first layout are visible?

Second:
The animation should start at the bottom of the Actionbar. I mean, if the layout is coming in, that he starts on bottom edge and not on the top of the screen. 
How can I set the start point of the animation?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your animation must have 4 xml's like slide_down_in, slide_down_out, slide_up_in, slide_up_out, and  use percentage like

slide_down_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

slide_down_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

slide_up_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

slide_up_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its Working**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FeedbackSuccessActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("title", "Success!");
    i.putExtra("message", "\n Profile Update Successfully \n ");
    startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down_in, R.anim.slide_down_out);
```

**slide_down_in**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

**slide_down_out**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```